# GooglePay with Braintree web, including shippingOptions with callback

Tags: reactjs, braintree, google-pay

I am using Google Pay with the Braintree web library. I am trying to integrate shippingOptions with a callback function.

Some example code

```
const paymentDataRequest = googlePaymentInstance.createPaymentDataRequest({
  merchantInfo: {
    merchantId: 'my-merchant-id-from-google',
  },
  transactionInfo: {
    currencyCode: 'USD',
    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
    totalPrice: '100.00',
  },
  shippingAddressRequired: true,
  shippingAddressParameters: {
    // parameters from this object https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#ShippingAddressParameters
  },
  shippingOptionRequired: true,
  shippingOptionParameters: {
    // parameters from this object https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#ShippingOptionParameters
    defaultSelectedOptionId: 'shipping-001',
    shippingOptions: [
      {
        id: 'shipping-001',
        label: '$0.00: Free shipping',
        description: 'Free Shipping delivered in 5 business days.',
      },
      {
        id: 'shipping-002',
        label: '$1.99: Standard shipping',
        description: 'Standard shipping delivered in 3 business days.',
      },
      {
        id: 'shipping-003',
        label: '$1000: Express shipping',
        description: 'Express shipping delivered in 1 business day.',
      },
    ],
  },
});

// Update card payment methods to require billing address
cosnt cardPaymentMethod = paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods;
cardPaymentMethod.parameters.billingAddressRequired = true;
cardPaymentMethod.parameters.billingAddressParameters = {
  format: 'FULL',
  phoneNumberRequired: true,
};

const paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
  environment: 'TEST', // or 'PRODUCTION'
});

paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest).then(function (response) {
  // handle response with googlePaymentInstance.parseResponse
  // (see below)
});
```

I believe i need to add the callbackIntents part into paymentDataRequest

```
  callbackIntents: ['SHIPPING_ADDRESS', 'SHIPPING_OPTION', 'PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION'],
  paymentDataCallbacks: {
    onPaymentDataChanged: onPaymentDataChanged,
    onPaymentAuthorized: onPaymentAuthorized,
  },
```

Not really sure what I need to do next?

Comment: do you face any issue? Or what is your actual problem?

Comment: issue im facing is I'm not sure how the callbacks would look like? for example 

const onPaymentDataChanged = () => { 
...

If i wanted to grab the selected shipping option.

Unsure how to achieve this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/client#onPaymentDataChanged ?

Comment: see my answer below. Like this you should be able to grab the selected shipping option.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the selected shipping option in combination with the Braintree Web SDK can be achieved like this:

Register the `onPaymentDataChanged` callback handler when creating the `PaymentsClient`:

```js
var paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
  environment: 'TEST',
  paymentDataCallbacks: {
    onPaymentDataChanged: onPaymentDataChanged
  },
});
```

Define the `callbackIntents`:

```js
googlePaymentInstance.createPaymentDataRequest({
  transactionInfo: {
    currencyCode: 'USD',
    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
    totalPrice: '100.00', // Your amount
  },
  shippingAddressRequired: true,
  shippingOptionRequired: true,
  shippingOptionParameters: {
    defaultSelectedOptionId: 'shipping-001',
    shippingOptions: [
      {
        id: 'shipping-001',
        label: '$0.00: Free shipping',
        description:
        'Free Shipping delivered in 5 business days.',
      },
      {
        id: 'shipping-002',
        label: '$1.99: Standard shipping',
        description:
        'Standard shipping delivered in 3 business days.',
      },
      {
        id: 'shipping-003',
        label: '$1000: Express shipping',
        description:
        'Express shipping delivered in 1 business day.',
      },
    ],
  },
  callbackIntents: [
    'SHIPPING_ADDRESS',
    'SHIPPING_OPTION',
  ],
});
```

Finally, see [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#implement) on how to react if the `onPaymentDataChanged` callback is invoked.